# Invalid Credentials Bcyrpt.compare()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
 
 
const User = require('../../models/User');
// @route Get api/auth
// @desc Test route
// @access Public
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
 
 
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error')
  }
});
 
 
// @route POST api/auth
// @desc Authenticate User And Get Token
// @access Public
router.post('/',
[
  check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
  check('password', 'Password is required').exists()
],
 
async (req, res) => {
 
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array()});
  }
 
  const { email, password } = req.body;
 
  try {
    // See if user exists
      let user = await User.findOne({ email})
 
      if (!user) {
        return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errors: [ { msg: 'Invalid Credentials Email' } ] });
      }
 
 
    // Make Sure Password matches
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
 
      if(!isMatch) {
        return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errors: [ { msg: 'Invalid Credentials Password' } ] });
      }
 
 
 
      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      }
 
      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        { expiresIn: 360000 },
        (err, token) => {
          if(err) throw err;
 
          res.json({ token });
        }
        );
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error')
  }
 
 
});
 
module.exports = router
```

In my database I have email and password
in my postman when i make POST request to https://localhost:5000/api/auth

the email is correct however I keep getting password is not correct with this       const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

```
  if(!isMatch) {
    return res
    .status(400)
    .json({ errors: [ { msg: 'Invalid Credentials Password' } ] });
  }
```

i console logged both password and user.password and it is the same value, i dont understand why !isMatch is keep getting triggered

can anyone help me

Comment: What do you mean when you say "i console logged both password and user.password and it is the same value". Where did you log it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `bcrypt.compare()` is:

> bcrypt.compare(plaintextPassword, hash)...

The first parameter is plaintext password and second is hash of the real password so it will not be the same value. As you mentioned that your `password` and `user.password` is the same value, I guess you forgot to hash user password before saving it to the DB. Please check the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) for more details.